# Simulate click from IFrame so a new tab opens.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to open up a new tab from within an IFrame. I am trying to make the triggered click event appear as if it has being initiated from outside the IFrame.

page.html

```
<div>

<iframe src="page1.html">

</iframe>
```

page1.html

```
<a href="path_to_other_page" id="link_to_other_page" target="_blank">link</a>
```

The above will open a new tab if clicked by user but I require the tab to open automatically.

```
<script>
    parent.window.open( '/path_to_other_page', '_blank' ); //will open a new window rather than tab but could be blocked

    $(function()
    {
        $("#link_to_other_page")[0].click(); //opens in new window   How do make the
        //click appear to be initiated from outside the iframe so a new tab opens?
    });
</script>
```

QUESTION:
How do I simulate clicking the link so the click appears to be initiated from outside the iframe?

```
############
```

Comment: @Alex doesnt work from within the iframe.

Comment: @NickMaroulis - This simply isn't possible.  The browser dictates how a link is handled if you are putting restrictions on a popup window (width, height, hide address bar, etc.).  Thus, it will be a matter of the user having their browser configured to open new windows in a new tab.  There just isn't anyway to force a tab over a window, not yet.  As for making an `iframe` link register as having happened outside the frame, you can make a pseudo frame to emulate the functionality of an `iframe` while maintaining standard page functionality.

Comment: @NickMaroulis I've verified that my solution does work (at least in browsers that typically open "_blank" in a new tab). Were you able to try it? Is there another road block that we are not aware of (browser, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="path_to_other_page" id="link_to_other_page" target="_blank">link</a>
```

You don't need javascript for that.

Note that you cannot force though whether the browser opens a new window or a new tab. That is on the browser (and user through the browsersettings) to decide.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is a browser issue. already spent much too long on finding out how to force the browser to open a new tab, till i found out that you just can't.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, both the main page and the iframed page should exist within the same domain.

Then, assuming that your link inside the **iframed** page has already the `target="_blank"` attribute, which it's needed (as it was already pointed out in previous answers) like :

```
<a href="path_to_other_page" id="link_to_other_page" target="_blank">link</a>
```

... you could add this script to the main page :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#myIframe").load(function () {
        var link = document.getElementById("myIframe").contentDocument.getElementById("link_to_other_page");
        $(link)[0].click();
    });
}); // ready
```

... or if you prefer the jQuery way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#myIframe").load(function () {
        var link = $("#myIframe").contents().find("#link_to_other_page");
        $(link)[0].click();
    });
}); // ready
```

**Consider**

- you may need to set an `ID` to your `<iframe>` tag (`#myIframe`) so you can manipulate it.
- you use the `.load()` method to make sure you won't attempt to trigger the `click` before the iframe is completely loaded.
- you don't need to set any javascript inside the iframed page.

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/parentPage01Oct14.html)**

**NOTE**: In my demo I used `setTimeout()` to trigger the `click` after 5 seconds so it will be more obvious.

**IMPORTANT** : as it was previously mentioned, it's up to the browser how to open the page. Chrome opens as pop up (as if you were using `window.open()`) any link where a `click` event if programmatically set (a manual click will open the page in a new tab though) while Firefox opens it in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Give ID to the Iframe and try the below code:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#iframeID").load(function () {
            var ifr = document.getElementById("iframeID")
            var anchors = iframeID.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i in anchors) {
                anchors[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

hope it helps

Comment: This may open a new window instead of a new tab. The questioner asks for opening a new tab. I noted that in my answer. You don't have to vote down for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could dummy in a link and "click" it in the parent window. It should react a bit more "natively".

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var link_html = $("#link_to_other_page").html();
        parent.window.$(link_html)[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

See http://jsbin.com/wifeba/1/ for the full example.

Comment: It's worth noting that this example assumes jQuery is also available in the parent window. If it is not, it would be trivial to provide a vanilla JS example also.